# How to move to next next page on Python Selenium throught the rel_name?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to build scraper for a house rent website, but I'm failing on move to next page. And show the follow error:

```
line 44, in <module> browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagination_hi']/[rel='next']").click()
```

And this is elements within which the pagination numbers are:

```
<div class="pagination_hi">
previous_page
</div><div class="pagination_hi">
<a href="https://www.28hse.com/rent/page-2" rel="next">next_page</a>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//a[text()='next_page']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='next_page']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='next_page']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='next_page']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='next_page']")
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: When I use your provided code trial 1, then I will get "AttributeError: module 'webdriver_manager.driver' has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath"

Comment: It was cause I was using `driver` in place of `browser`, please see updated code above

Answer (score 0):

Correct XPath syntax should be

```
//div[@class='pagination_hi']/a[@rel='next']
```

You can also try to locate node by link text:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("next_page").click()
```